# Using datetime.strptime when data is a little messy : extra spaces, Jan or January

Tags: python, datetime, datetime-format, python-datetime

Currently the text I am dealing with are dates with a somewhat standard format, however the data isn't super clean.

For example the text can be in these formats:

```
Jan. 1, 2021 (dot after Jan)
Jan, 1 2021 (comma after Jan)
January, 1 2020 (Full month with comma)
Jan,  1 2020 (two spaces after Jan, instead of one)
```

I'm not quite sure how to deal with this.
I want to convert these strings into `2021-01-01` format.

My plan was to convert to datetime object, and then convert back to string.

However when using `strptime`, the pattern seemingly needs to be rigid,
and doesn't allow for regex like patterns.

```
print(datetime.datetime.strptime(timestamp, '%b %d, %Y'))
```

instead of something like `'%b|%B\s[.,]?`

Anyone have suggestions as to how to convert my text into year-month-day format?

Comment: Did you consider using a regex to normalize, then `strptime`?

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking use regex sub, however off the top of my head, I didn't really know to handle the months. I was assuming I would need to create a dictionary mapping for each month, which seems kind of tedious.

Comment: Look into libraries like `arrow` or `dateparser`, they are very lenient in the formats they can handle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the [dateutil](https://pypi.org/project/python-dateutil/) library, (it's one of the most downloaded pypi packages)

```
>>> from dateutil import parser
>>>
>>> print(parser.parse("Jan. 1, 2021"))
2021-01-01 00:00:00
>>>
>>> print(parser.parse("Jan, 1 2021"))
2021-01-01 00:00:00
>>>
>>> print(parser.parse("January, 1 2020"))
2020-01-01 00:00:00
>>>
>>> print(parser.parse("Jan,  1 2020"))
2020-01-01 00:00:00
```

Comment: note: parser will raise an Exception if there are random other characters in the string (e.g. from an imperfect OCR of the characters in an image).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a regex that works for the cases you've given.

```
import re

pattern = """(?ix)   # ignore case, verbose
   (?P<month>
        jan(uary)?
       |feb(uary)?
       |mar(ch)?
       |apr(il)?
       |may
       |jun(e)?
       |jul(y)?
       |aug(ust)?
       |sep(tember)?
       |oct(ober)?
       |nov(ember)?
       |dec(ember)?
   )
   \D+
   (?P<day>\d(\d)?)
   \D+
   (?P<year>\d\d(\d\d)?)
"""

regex = re.compile(pattern)

testcases = """
Jan. 1, 2021 (dot after Jan)
Jan, 1 2021 (comma after Jan)
January, 1 2020 (Full month with comma)
Jan,  1 2020 (two spaces after Jan, instead of one)
""".strip().splitlines()

for test in testcases:
    print(test, end=' => ')
    m = regex.search(test)
    if m:
        print(m.groupdict())
    else:
        print(m)
```

Output:

```
Jan. 1, 2021 (dot after Jan) => {'month': 'Jan', 'day': '1', 'year': '2021'}
Jan, 1 2021 (comma after Jan) => {'month': 'Jan', 'day': '1', 'year': '2021'}
January, 1 2020 (Full month with comma) => {'month': 'January', 'day': '1', 'year': '2020'}
Jan,  1 2020 (two spaces after Jan, instead of one) => {'month': 'Jan', 'day': '1', 'year': '2020'}
```

That said, using the dateutil library, as suggested by foxyblue, is probably more robust.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use a library you could just be a bit brutish about it:

```
def normalise(date):
    month_name, day, year = date.replace(',', '').split()
    short_month_name = month_name[:3]
    return f'{short_month_name} {day} {year}'
```

Usage:

```
>>> normalise('January, 1 2020')
'Jan 1 2020'
```

etc.

Then you can parse it normally with `datetime`.